# Переброска события onClick из одного класса в обработчик событий другого класса

Tags: reactjs

Как передать событие onClick из одного класса в обработчик событий другого класса? (Клик по кнопке в Дропдауне в Файл_1 должен открыть Модальное окно (Файл_2).

Файл_1

```
class  NavMenu extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
        <div id="sidebar-menu" className='sideBarMenuContainer'>
            <Navbar fluid className='sidebar' inverse >
                <Navbar.Header>
                        <a>Menu</a>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="Dropdown" >
                            <MenuItem eventKey={1.1} href="#" onClick={здесь_открыть_Modal}>Show Modal</MenuItem>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
export default NavMenu;
```

Файл_2

```
class Trigger extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }
    handleHide() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
   }
    handleShow(){
         this.setState({show:true});
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    container={this}
                    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
                            Contained Modal
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        Elit est explicabo ipsum eaque dolorem blanditiis doloribus sed id
                        ipsam, beatae, rem fuga id earum? Inventore et facilis obcaecati.
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleHide}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
        );
    }
}
export default Trigger;


Файл App

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
 import NavMenu from './NavMenu';
 import MapLayer from './MapLayer'
import Modal from './Modal';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
             <div >
                    <NavMenu />
              <div className='MapLayer'>

                  <MapLayer  />
                  <Modal />

              </div>
            </div>
      )
  }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Я смутно представляю, о чём вопрос. Не могли бы вы хоть псевдокодом или схемой указать, что и куда нужно прокинуть и как колбек потом должен быть вызван? А то в текущем виде не уверен, как лучше ответить на вопрос.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Модал открывается как? Ему props какой-то передается?

Comment: И есть ли какой-то родительский App, где оба компонента расположены? И как они там расположены?

Comment: Родительский App есть, (см в коде). Модал должен открыться по изменению стейта :

Comment: handleHide() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
   }
    handleShow(){
         this.setState({show:true});
    }

Answer (score 0):

Решение. Мож кому пригодится.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Nav, NavItem, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';



// -----MODAL-------
export class Trigger extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">
                        Contained Modal
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    Elit est explicabo ipsum eaque dolorem blanditiis doloribus sed id
                    ipsam, beatae, rem fuga id earum? Inventore et facilis obcaecati.
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}


class  NavMenu extends Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            mdlShow: false,
        };
    }
    render() {
        let mdlClose = () => this.setState({ mdlShow: false });
        return (
        <div id="sidebar-menu" className='sideBarMenuContainer'>
            <Navbar fluid className='sidebar' inverse >

                <Navbar.Header>
                    {/*<Navbar.Brand>*/}
                        {/*<a>Sales</a>*/}
                    {/*</Navbar.Brand>*/}
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>

                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="Конвертер" >
                            <MenuItem eventKey={1.1} href="#" onClick={() => this.setState({ mdlShow: true })}>Конвертер</MenuItem>

                            <MenuItem eventKey={1.3} href="#" disabled>Очистить карту</MenuItem>
                            <Trigger show={this.state.mdlShow} onHide={mdlClose} />
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2}>Тепловая карта</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={3} className='ItemEmpty'>Item 3</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>

            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
export default NavMenu;
```